# TextToColumns produces Run-time error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

I have pasted a text file with fixed widths into column A. I tried recording the steps but when running the macro after repasting the text into column A get the following error- Run-time error 1004

Macro will be used to complete the same task on multiple files all with the same column spacing.
Thanks for any help!

```
Sub Text2Columns()
    Columns("A:A").Select

    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("a3"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(48, 1), Array(65, 1), Array(88, 1), Array(110, 1), _
        Array(131, 1), Array(154, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 12.86


End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a message with the error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear on where `.Range("A3")` came from but as you are selecting the entire column to process (with A1 being the active cell), that is likely the root of your problem.

```
Sub Text2Columns()
    With Sheets("Sheet1")   '<-set to the worksheet!!!
        With .Columns("A:A")
            .TextToColumns Destination:=.Columns(1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                FieldInfo:=Array(Array(48, 1), Array(65, 1), Array(88, 1), Array(110, 1), _
                Array(131, 1), Array(154, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
            .ColumnWidth = 12.86
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for more methods on getting away from relying on select and activate to accomplish your goals.